# Automating files in TeamCity

Tags: deployment, server, web-applications, teamcity, integration

What is the best way to automate commit mdf/ldf files to version control in TeamCity?

As of right now, we cannot see an automation. We have searched everywhere and can't find a way. I don't really know how to write my own code to make this happen and it seems that is what it is going to take. That is why I am reaching out to the IT community for suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean by `automate commit mdf/ldf files`? Do you want to geneerate\update these files, commit them and push to the branch from TeamCity?